# Why doesn't Rails return a Range of TimeWithZone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 6 app, I have the `reserved_between` `tsrange` attribute.

In PostgreSQL, the values are stored as UTC (no problem here) and now I'm trying to localize them to a different timezone, but it seems to me the conversion doesn't work.

Here a small script to demonstrate it.

```
p "UTC: #{Reservation.first.reserved_time}"
Time.use_zone('Europe/Rome') do
  p "ROME: #{Reservation.first.reserved_time}"
end
```

Which fetching the value `["2019-08-05 15:28:03.443474","2019-08-05 15:58:03.443487"]` should print out

```
"UTC: 2019-08-05 15:28:03 UTC..2019-08-05 15:58:03 UTC"
"ROME: 2019-08-05 17:28:03 CEST +02:00..2019-08-05 17:58:03 CEST +02:00"
```

but actually prints out

```
"UTC: 2019-08-05 15:28:03 UTC..2019-08-05 15:58:03 UTC"
"ROME: 2019-08-05 15:28:03 UTC..2019-08-05 15:58:03 UTC"
```

I found an old issue on the Rails Github repo https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21116 about this but it seems to have been fixed here https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/302e92359cc88258ae15a82454c58408a4b8157e

But unfortunately

> ... This does not automatically make ranges time zone aware, ...

So, how can I to get a `Range` of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instead of   a `Range` of `Time`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the `reserved_time` reader on `Reservation` to convert your `Range` to `TimeWithZone`:

```rb
    def reserved_time
      range = read_attribute(:reserved_time)
      (range.begin.in_time_zone..range.end.in_time_zone)
    end
```